# Centos, How to delete files with full root (but not full file system), with out repartitioning

Tags: centos, root, root-filesystem, tmp

Nvidia has screwed me and kept every single old version of CUDA since cuda 10 including every minor version inside of root totaling up to nearly 30 gigabytes of my 50 gigabyte root partition, and upon updating, It finally took enough space I could no longer actually complete any system updates.  I found some files I could safely delete, but I can't delete them, since no new files can be created in tmp because root is full.  10 gigabytes of this are yum cache files of which 9 gigs of this are Nvidia files...

I don't want to repartition.  I want to just delete files I know won't cause issues. Every single response has been to repartition, I don't want that I want to delete the files I know I want to delete.  I'm not sure why this extremely simple task is seemingly impossible...

Comment: How did you install CUDA?

Comment: truncate -s 0 /path/to/file. It works to remove a file even if the disk is full

Comment: Cleaning the yum cache is easy enough.  `yum clean all`

Comment: "No new files can be created in tmp because root is full" suggests that you are using some tool is allowing you to "undelete" files by saving copies in /tmp. Use `\rm filename` in a console to bypass any aliases to remove a file.